# how to update/upgrade a linux machine using pure python script

Tags: python, linux, shell

I want to update/upgrade a virtual machine using the console. I am a beginner to python and I can do this on shell, but I want to do this using python script.

I'm aware that I can use the subprocess call or the os.system command, but then that is just hard - porting the shell script to python.

Is there a pure python way to do apt-get update and apt-get upgrade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `check_call()` from subprocess that run command with argument :

```
from subprocess import STDOUT, check_call
import os

check_call(['apt-get', 'update'], stderr=STDOUT)
```